# Convert a .txt file with doubles to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `.txt` file with this content: `"17.23;12.1;20.34;88.23523;"`.
I want to read this file as doubles into an `ArrayList`. And eventually print the `ArrayList` (and eventually print the min. and max., but I don't think that will be a problem after solving this).

**But I only get the output "[ ]".**

What am I doing wrong? I've been struggling with this for embarrassing 15+ hours, browsed here, youtube, course books...

My code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      File myFile = new File("text.txt");
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

      ArrayList<Double> aList = new ArrayList<>();
      
      while (scan.hasNextDouble()) {  
          double nextInput = scan.nextDouble();
          if (nextInput != 0) {
              break;  
          }  
        
          aList.add(nextInput);
      }

      System.out.println(alist);
}
```

Comment: `if (nextInput != 0) break;` why do you need this line? Because of them your code is never supposed to add something to an arrayList given your input

Comment: Since your file has numbers separated by a semi-colon, you won't be able to read them using `scan.hasNextDouble()` by default. However, there are so many ways to do it e.g. reading a line as string and process each number from it after splitting it on the semi-colon. Another way is to override the default delimiter etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply by changing the delimiter.  This works by reading from a String but you can also do it from a file.  It is up to you to put the values in some data structure.  This presumes your default locale uses ',' as a decimal point.

```
String str = "17,23;12,1;20,34;88,23523;";

Scanner scan = new Scanner(str);
scan.useDelimiter("[;]+");
while(scan.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println(scan.nextDouble());
}
```

prints

```
17.23
12.1
20.34
88.23523
```

Comment: Comma is a decimal separator in OP's question, not number separator

Comment: It is unlikely that both `,` and `;` are value separators. It is far more likely that `;` is the value separator and that `,` is a locale-specific decimal point, especially since the "Uppgift" word in the file name is Swedish and Sweden uses `,` as decimal point.

Comment: Well, the OP didn't specify that in the question (but it does make sense)  so I caveated it in my answer.  Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Hi, Andreas is right. I've now changed this to the more international standard! Big thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

You should configure your scanner so it will accept:

1. `;` as a delimiter
2. `,` as a decimal separator

Working code is:

```
File myFile = new File("input.txt");

// Swedish locale uses ',' as a decimal separator
Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile).useDelimiter(";").useLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("sv-SE"));

ArrayList<Double> aList = new ArrayList<>();

while (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
    double nextInput = scan.nextDouble();
    aList.add(nextInput);
}

System.out.println(aList);
```

With output `[17.23, 12.1, 20.34, 88.23523]`

Comment: Great answer, +1 from me, though I believe the "Uppgift" word in the file name is Swedish and Sweden does use `,` as well, so changing `Locale.FRENCH` to `Locale.forLanguageTag("sv-SE")` would likely be more accurate for the question. Same result, of course.

Comment: Yes, of course, French is just an example ("ru-RU" locale works too)

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` works by splitting the input into tokens, where tokens are separated by whitespaces (by default). Since there are no whitespaces in the text, the first/only token is the entire text, and since that text is not a valid `double` value, `hasNextDouble()` returns `false`.

Two ways to fix that:

- Change the token separator to `;`:

  ```java
  scan.useDelimiter(";");
  ```
- Read the file with `BufferedReader` and use `split()`:

  ```java
  String filename = "text.txt";
  try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filename))) {
      for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
          String[] tokens = line.split(";");
          // code here
      }
  }
  ```

That will now result in the following tokens: `17,23`, `12,1`, `20,34`, `88,23523`.

Unfortunately, none of those are valid `double` values, because they use locale-specific formatting, i.e. the decimal point is a `,`, not a `.`.

Which means that if you kept using `Scanner`, you can't use `hasNextDouble()` and `nextDouble()`, and if you changed to use `split()`, you can't use `Double.parseDouble()`.

You need to use a `NumberFormat` to parse locale-specific number formats. Since "Uppgift" looks Swedish, we can use `NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("sv-SE"))`, or simply `NumberFormat.getInstance()` if your default locale is Sweden.

```java
String filename = "text.txt";
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filename))) {
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("sv-SE"));
    
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        List<Double> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (String token : line.split(";")) {
            double value = format.parse(token).doubleValue();
            aList.add(value);
        }
        
        System.out.println(aList); // Prints: [17.23, 12.1, 20.34, 88.23523]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your file has numbers separated by a semi-colon, you won't be able to read them using `scan.hasNextDouble()` by default. However, there are so many ways of doing it e.g.

1. Override the default delimiter.
2. Reading a line as string and process each number from it after splitting it on the semi-colon.

**Option-1:**

```
scan.useDelimiter(";")
```

Note that since your file has the comma instead of the dot as the decimal symbol, you can use a `Locale` in which it is the default.

```
scan.useLocale(Locale.FRANCE);
```

Also, the following code block in your code will cause the loop to be terminated after reading the first number itself as the first number in your file in not equal to zero. Simply remove these lines in order to get the desired result:

```
if (nextInput != 0) {
    break;  
}
```

**Option-2:**

Read a line, split it on a semi-colon, replace the comma with a dot, parse each element from the resulting array into `Double` and store the same into `aList`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File myFile = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

        List<Double> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextInput = scan.nextLine();
            String[] arr = nextInput.split(";");
            for (String s : arr) {
                aList.add(Double.valueOf(s.replace(",", ".")));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(aList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[17.23, 12.1, 20.34, 88.23523]
```

An alternative to replace comma with dot is to use `NumberFormat` as shown below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        File myFile = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
        List<Double> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextInput = scan.nextLine();
            String[] arr = nextInput.split(";");
            for (String s : arr) {
                aList.add(format.parse(s).doubleValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(aList);
    }
}
```